# Issues when converting dates from Excel to R

Tags: r, excel

I'm trying to convert a list of dates in a data frame.
On the excel file, it is formatted as Date and the rows are filled correctly in the dd/mm/yyyy format, but when I upload it to RStudio, it returns as a numeric format (17/07/1911 turns to 4216, for example).

If i try to convert it to Date, all the fields become "NA", except the first one (24/7/1898), which is formatted correctly.

What exactly am I doing wrong, and why only the 1898 date is formatted accordingly?

Both Windows and Excel standard dates are set in dd/mm/yyyy (pt_BR)

The file is [attached](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Xuyz6gGXJGX46rQtOoJnZDV5DoxvqfHU/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=110628182835169074342&rtpof=true&sd=true) here

```
library(readr)
library(readxl)

Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME","English")
df <- read_xlsx("path of .xlsx file")
View(df)

class(df$data) # class is Character
df$data <- as.Date(df$data, format = "%d/%m/%Y", locale="en_US.UTF-8") #formats 24/7/1898 #correctly. Changing locale to pt_BR did not work either
```

Answer (score 0):

Your data seems to contain a mix of date formats. The first value 24/07/1898 is dd/mm/yyyy. The second value, 7/17/1911 has to be m/dd/yyyy since there is no month 17. Some of the other values are ambiguous as to month and day, for example 1/2/1928.

This code:

```
library(readxl)
dataset <- read_excel("data.xlsx", col_types = c("date"))
```

converts the values in row 2 onwards to dates, assuming that they are m/dd/yyyy, and sets the first value to NA.

I think that's the best you can do given this data, but you should try to figure out what the date format is supposed to be, especially given the ambiguous cases.

Comment: Hi Neil, thanks for contributing. 
I thought so too at first, but the settings seem fine. I made a test, changing 1898 to 1989, and all the dates converted fine, so i'm guessing it might have something to do with how it interprets dates prior to 1899, which is when Windows dates begins, but I imagine there must have some way to fix that.

Comment: I used the "openxlsx" package instead of readxl, and it converted all the dates correctly, except for 1898, so I changed it manually, and now it works. Anyway, after further research, it seems this kind of issue is something we have to live with. Thanks